# Laravel controller doesn't pass the variables to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have watched a youtube tutorial about Laravel. This is the code. I started studying Laravel.

```
 <?php

class Authors_Controller extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;
public function get_index(){

    $view = View::make('authors.index',array('name'=>'Jedi'))->with('age','18');
    $view->location='somewhere';
    $view['favorite'] = 'bacon';    
    return $view;
 }
}
?>
```

view code

```
<?
 php echo $name;
 echo $age;
 echo $location;
 echo $favorite;
?>
```

Once I ran the localhost, I get an error that states that the variables are undefined.

Comment: The line break in `<?php` in your view is likely the problem - I don't think the PHP interpreter is reading this at all. Remove the line break.

Comment: it made sure it is a php file.

Comment: Are all of the variables not defined or just some?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<?php

class Authors_Controller extends BaseController {

public $restful = true;
public function get_index(){

    $view = View::make('authors.index',array('name'=>'Jedi'))->with('age','18');
    $view->location='somewhere';
    $view['favorite'] = 'bacon';    

   return View::make('foldername/filename')->with('view',$view);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Would you explain, in the body of your answer, what you have changed and why? We tend to discourage code-only answers here, since readers have to work out what has changed, and they still don't know why those changes would be used.